# How to use git on a server - fix conq username

Tags: git, github, ssh

I recently changed my hosting company, as with it i have a new username

> nickwebd

I have a bitbucket account with this username

> nickimola

Whit the new hosting company, i have already set up:

- ssh
- public key
- made git available everywhere using this command: `alias git="/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git"`

now, when i try to clone a repository, it says

> access denied (public key)

and if i run `ssh -v hg@bitbucket.org` this is the full log:

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nickwebd/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:nickimola
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nickwebd/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
nickwebd@cloud05 [~]# debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
```

now, the hosting company support said this:

> The logs show you were truing to use nickimola
>
> If you can re-test using nickwebd with your cPanel password this will
>   then work fine.

problem is: I'm totally new with this kind of setup as this is my first time.
Where and how should i change the username? is it possible to keep my bitbucket account as it is (so that i don't have to change source tree and my local repos as well) but making it available for the new one?

Just to specify, i'm using a mac and the server runs cpanel (if it helps in some ways)
And also, when i try to run `ssh -v hg@bitbucket.org` from my local machine, the response is

> logged in as nickimola.
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is
>   disabled.

please help i'm working on this for days!
Thanks

**QUICK UPDATE**

i found that the key agent wasn't running, so i started it, checked the identity, no identity found, so trying to add it. trying cause when i type:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

it ask my for the passphrase but when i try to paste it (or even write it) it returns this:

> debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE

and i can't obviously add the passphrase correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure about bitbucket, but on github it is required that you `git configure user.name` and `git configure user.email` before being able to connect.

Comment: can you please tell me how? from where?

Comment: sorry, i can just google it to be fair :)

Comment: See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-your-username-for-bitbucket-actions-272597445.html

Comment: and after that? i mean, i have to push to remote and that's it?

Comment: Just give that a try, and see if you're able to connect to BB now that you have the right name and email configured. If that doesn't do it, I'm not quite sure where to go as I've never used bb.

Comment: still nothing on the server, it is still trying to connect using the old username

Comment: It may not have any inpact when testing the connection, but have you tried testing the connection with the `git` user (`ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`)?

Comment: You may already have read this https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html

Comment: @joran i tried your suggestions, but still no luck, still the same error as before (access denied (public key))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "conq username" listed here is the Bitbucket account associated with the SSH key you're using. Bitbucket already recognizes that SSH key as one on your Bitbucket account (nickimola), so your connection was mostly successful. Your hosting provider's support team was not very helpful here, as the hosting provider account name has zero connection to your Bitbucket account name.

Also, the ssh-agent needs to add the private key, not the public key. The command you need is

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Once you've added the private key, try the "ssh -v hg@bitbucket.org" again. (That command is only good for debugging, BTW, and it's the same result as if you use "git" instead of "hg".) If you've associated the "nickwebd" account's public key with your Bitbucket username, then you should get the same result from the test on both your hosting provider's system as on your own system.

By the way, if the hosting provider's system will only be pulling commits from Bitbucket, then you should consider setting that key as a deployment key: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys

Comment: Thanks Jim, i'll try what you sying tonight and i'll let you know.

Comment: thank you very much! i finally managed to clone the repo i needed! thank again for your answer.